# Use a left join in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-4, query-builder

I'm getting started with Laravel and I can't show information from a object:

```
$questions = DB::table('Questions')
                ->join('Users', 'Users.id', '=', 'Questions.user_id')
                ->join('Profiles', 'Profiles.user_id', '=', 'Users.id')
                ->leftjoin('Answers', 'Answers.question_id', '=', 'Questions.id')
                ->orderBy('Questions.created_at','desc')
                ->get();
```

The query works fine but when I try to show in blade template doing something like this:

```
@foreach ($question->answers as $answer )
      ...
endforeach
```

I have the message

> Undefined property: stdClass::$answers (View: C:...\app\views\home.blade.php)

This is the question and answer configuration

```
class Question extends Eloquent {

public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('User');
}

public function answers()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Answer');
}
}

class Answer extends Eloquent {

public function question()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('Question');
}
}

users:
      -id
      -email
      -photo
      -name
questions:
      -id
      -content
      -user_id
answers:
      -id
      -content
      -user_id
      -question_id
```

Comment: I did a bit of digging to see why you might have this problem, but nothing really came up. If you're happy to do a bit of debugging, this is the code which should make `$questions->answer` work: http://laravel.com/api/source-class-Illuminate.Database.Eloquent.Model.html#1851

Comment: When asking questions, please don't write in all-lower-case. Questions don't have to be perfect, especially if English is not your first language, but we do want to keep them readable for others in the future.